# Unable to position a second ColumnText along x axis itextpdf

Tags: java, itext

I am having two separate Column text on my onEndPage method. The first `ColumnText` get Placed properly but the second one wont move along x axis. Here is my snippet.

```
 ///AddFirst ColumnText
            Font bfont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 13, Font.BOLD);
            cb.roundRectangle(100f, 1150f, 400f, 100f, 5f);
            cb.stroke();
            ColumnText btext = new ColumnText(cb);
            btext.setSimpleColumn(110f, 1250f, 400f, 100f);
            btext.addElement(new Paragraph("BRANCH: MYBRANCH", bfont));
            btext.addElement(new Paragraph("ADDRESS: P.O Box 15524", bfont));
            btext.addElement(new Paragraph("PHONE NUMBER: 0720000000/072000000", bfont));
            btext.go();


            cb.roundRectangle(650f, 1150f, 400f, 100f, 5f);
            cb.stroke();

        ///Add Head office ColumnText
            ColumnText htext = new ColumnText(cb);
            htext.setSimpleColumn(850f, 1250f, 400f, 500f);//This wont position on x axis
            htext.addElement(new Paragraph("HEAD OFFICE", bfont));
            htext.addElement(new Paragraph("TEL: 0720000002/072000000", bfont));
            htext.addElement(new Paragraph("MOBILE: 0720000000/072000000", bfont));
            htext.addElement(new Paragraph("EMAIL: email@domain", bfont));
            htext.addElement(new Paragraph("WEBSITE: https://website.com/", bfont));
            htext.go();
```

What am I missing here. I though if I changed `850f` the second column text should move freely anywhere in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You mis-interpret the third and fourth parameter of the `ColumnText` method `setSimpleColumn`!

You appear to think they are width and height of the rectangle while the first and second position it somewhere.

Instead the third and fourth parameter just like the the first and second parameter constitute the coordinates of a corner of the rectangle!

Thus, by changing the `850f` in

```
htext.setSimpleColumn(850f, 1250f, 400f, 500f)
```

a bit, the box horizontally still starts at `x=400f` (third parameter, the **x** coordinate of the second given corner). Furthermore, you add only relatively short paragraphs to the `ColumnText`, so you don't see them breaking differently after changing the horizontal end of the box unless you make the first parameter considerably smaller.

Thus, if you want to change where the `ColumnText` box starts horizontally, change the *lower* of the *first* and *third* parameter values.

As an aside, it is common to use the first and second coordinates for the lower left corner and the third and forth one for the upper right corner. This also is what the names of the method parameter try to suggest:

```
public void setSimpleColumn(final float llx, final float lly, final float urx, final float ury)
```